# Not able to generate signed .apk due to including proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

I am trying to generate a signed .apk in android studio. But I have not been able to do the same showing me the following error. I have tried searching a lot and found no solution. Please see the following code:

> Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find
>   referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
>   Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't
>   find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
>   Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't
>   find referenced class java.nio.file.Paths
>   Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't
>   find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
>   Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support:
>   can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
>   Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support:
>   can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

1.Try disabling minify. Set minify to false on release build type and try to generate Apk.

2.Exclude the required java class files from minify using the proguard file. Libraries including Jackson usually needs to be excluded from minify.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out....If I do the 1st way u told, there will be no use of using jackson as i wont be getting benefit of proguard. 2nd) And if try the second way then i get the following error...

???
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.
libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue (AnnotationAccess.java:688)
java.lang.Class.getAnnotation (Class.java:344)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std. (Unknown Source)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.defaultInstance (Unknown Source)